# Can't access files on mounted HD from inside a flatpack application

Tags: gnome, flatpak

I am using the [Zotero Flatpack](https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.zotero.Zotero.flatpakref) from Flathub on my Linux machine. Unfortunately I can't access my files which are on an extra hard drive mounted in `/media/user/XYZ`. It is possible to access all files, that are directly in `/home/user` though, but there I use symbolic links to refer to some directories on an other disc, the which I can't access. The only way to work around this issue is, to mount the directory of hard drive `XYZ` into the directory in `home` but this is not desirable in my use case.

Is there any way to grand permission to the flatpack to access those files?

PS: Can we please convince the Gnome devs to stop that flatpack madness. I using Linux because of its package system!

Comment: This can be achieved with the flatpak override command (i.e "sudo flatpak override --filesystem=/path/to/possibly external zotero folder/ org.zotero.Zotero") after installing zotero from flathub. See the manpages for "flatpak override" for more information. Actually I really appreciate the efforts to create a universal linux packaging system btw...

Comment: @dalanicolai : you should make this an answer, to make it more visible. It solved the problem I had with a Dropbox Flatpak install.

Comment: @mivk Okay, will do that then... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the flatpak override command (i.e `sudo flatpak override --filesystem="/path/to/possibly external zotero folder/" org.zotero.Zotero`) after installing zotero from flathub. See the manpages for "flatpak override" for more information. Actually I really appreciate the efforts to create a universal linux packaging system btw...

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, if you use [flatseal](https://github.com/tchx84/flatseal), which is a permission utility for flatpak, toggling this solves the problem:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To mount that partition anywhere you want you need to:

- Go to `/mnt/` and create subdirectories. Name these subfolders something like (mntpnt1, mntpnt2, mntpnt3...etc).
- Then to mount that partition, first you need to find out whether it's readable/available and what it's mapped like.

  - List all the detected disks, all partitions and see where mounted partitions have been mounted, you can do that by running the command `lsblk | more`
  - To mount one of the mountpoints run `mount /dev/sd(X)(Y) -v -w /mnt/mntpnt1`

Important to note that you can add another directory on your Desktop and create `mntpnt(X)` subdirectories, then MountPoints in it for easier and faster access.